# Dynamic functions for dynamic forms

Tags: angular

I'm generating reactive forms out of a JSON object model (similar like this one https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form, but much more complex).

simple example:

```
{

"id": "1"

"type":"input"

},

{

"id": "2"

"type":"dropDown"

}
```

The generation of the form works fine. Now I would like to implement dependencies between controls.

Example 1: user deletes data in an input. All following controls should be disabled
Example 2: user selects a value in a drop down. The next drop down should use the selected value, execute a rest service with the value as parameter and display the received data. 
... (I have at least 6 different cases).

The problem is I don't have a component during development time, as the form is generating out of the JSON object model at runtime.

My basic idea is to define a custom function in my JSON object model, that will be executed when a specific event occurs:

```
{
"id": "1"
"type":"input"
"dependencies": {
  "click": "clickFunctionForComponent1(1, 2)"
   }  
},
{
"id": "2"
"type":"dropDown"
}
```

"somewhere" else I implement the function

```
clickFunctionForComponent1(currentControl otherControl) {
  if (currentCuontrol has valid data) otherControl.data = loadDataForOtherControl(); 
}
```

Do you have any (other) ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to invoke the method.
I tried with this.

```
    function  clickFunctionForComponent1() {
      console.log('worked');
    }

    let data = JSON.parse(`{
      "id": "1",
      "type": "input",
      "dependencies": {
        "click": "clickFunctionForComponent1()"
      }
    }`);

console.log(eval(data.dependencies.click));
```

Or

You can try this

```
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
   }


  ngOnInit() {

    let data = JSON.parse(`{
      "id": "1",
      "type": "input",
      "dependencies": {
        "click": "clickFunctionForComponent1"
      }
    }`);
      console.log(data);
      let methodName = data.dependencies.click;
      console.log(this[methodName]());
      // console.log(eval(data.dependencies.click));
  }
clickFunctionForComponent1() {
  console.log('work');
}

}
```

Comment: I thought about it too, but the Angular version $scope.$eval
But I'm trying to find better approach.

Comment: Or you can define the method in the class scope and invoke it like this 
      `let methodName = data.dependencies.click;
      console.log(this[methodName]());`
where data.dependencies.click is the method name(clickFunctionForComponent1)

Comment: which class scope do you mean? I've only a dynamic-forum-builder-component for all forms.

Comment: I am talking about the component scope. Not any method scope. So that you can access it with this[methodName]

Comment: I your first comment you wrote 'Or you can define the method in the class scope' What do you exactly mean? Like I said, I have only a class/component: dynamic-form-builder.component.ts for ALL forms. Is your suggestion to define all methods, for all forms, in this class (hardcoded) and than assign them with this[methodName] (which is defined in the JSON-file)?

Comment: @DevashishSharma, I think that use "eval" can not work because in the minimify process executed when angular build  the application in production, angular change the name of the functions, Are you check if you can use it?

Comment: @Eliseo I didn't build it and check. I think it should work in production because eval is a built in function.

Comment: The problen is that the funcion "clickFunction" is called as, e.g. "cf". So you can not evaluate clickFunction. I'm un hurry, but prior to make a laaarge app, check it with an example

Comment: @Eliseo, If there is a problem with eval then you can use the second way to achieve that (this[methodName]()). Also, eval is not the suggested way to do that by so many sources.